# How do I get two topics that have the same partition key and the number of partitions land on the same consumer within a kafka streams application

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to create a Kafka Streams service where

1. I am trying to initialize a cache in a processor, that will then be updated by consuming messages with a topic say "nodeStateChanged" for a partition key lets say locationId.
2. I need to check the node state when I consume another topic lets say "Report" again keyed by the same locationId. Effectively I am joining with the table created by nodeStateChanged.

How do I ensure that all the updates for nodeStateChanged fall on the same instance as the Report topic so that the lookup for a location is possible when a new report is recieved. Do 1 and 2 need to be created by the same topology or it okay to create two seperate topologies that share the same APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything. Kafka Streams will *always* co-partition topics. Ie, if you have a sub-topology that reads from multiple topics with N partitions each, you get N tasks and each task is processing corresponding partitions, ie, task 0 processes partitions zero of both input topics, task 1 processes partitions one of both input topics, etc.